# bundlerを引数なしで実行したものはbundle installと同じ？

Tags: bundler

[rails/rails-dev-box: A virtual machine for Ruby on Rails core development](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box)
に
`vagrant@rails-dev-box:/vagrant/rails$ bundle`
とあり `bundle install`ではなく`bundle`とだけ実行しているのですが、
これは`bundle install`とまったく同じと考えてよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私もどこかで見た覚えがあるのですが、見つからないですね〜。

ソースを覗いたら、default_task で定義されていました。

https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb#L45

```
default_task :install
```

Answer (score 1):

はい、単なる alias だったはずです。
どこかの文書で見た覚えがあるんですが、該当のものが見つかりませんでした。